Linear velocity on a circle
Consider a ball rotating around the z-axis with constant angular velocity $\vec{\omega}$, then the linear velocity $\vec{v}$ is given by $\vec{v} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}$. It is easy to understand when the reference frame is centered at the origin.
If the origin was to be set on a fixed point on the circle, how can I apply the formula? I am confused about the meaning of $\vec{r}$, is it a vector connecting the origin to a point on the circle? If it is, then the linear velocity is 0 when the ball passes the origin as shown in the bottom picture. But the linear velocity should not be in reality.


is the particle in second figure still moving in circle with constant angular velocity with respect to its centre?

Yes, I meant exactly that.

You shouldn't be thinking about an origin, or, in this context, about $x$ and $y$ axes. $\vec r$ is the displacement vector from the centre of the circle to the ball travelling round the circle. $\vec \omega$ is a vector of magnitude equal to the angular velocity of the ball about the centre of the circle, and direction normal to the plane of motion. Since $\vec \omega$ and $\vec r$ have constant magnitudes, so does $\vec v=\vec \omega \times \vec r$.

You can think of it as a shift of origin.

$\vec v = \vec \omega \times (\vec r - \vec r')= \vec \omega \times \vec r''$

Thanks for your answer, but I can't see the picture.
